# Is possible to merge two arrays of different type into single array in java?

Tags: arrays, sorting

[Image of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbGVI.png)Im trying to merge to arrays of different types into a single one but I have a problem with the data type. When I try to go trough the secon array i gives me an error of incompatible types.

[Image of output expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFd4p.png)
After merging the arrays I want to sort them. When printing I need them to print like this

Comment: Two arrays of what? They would need to share a common parent class, which with sortability requires them to at least be some parent type `T` such that `T extends Comparable<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

I make this: c[ i+ arrWords.length] = arrNums[i].toString();

I don't understand deepToString, but I ever use toString to make this things.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).